# Drupal: enabling Media Mover S3 module causes Server 500 error

Tags: drupal, amazon-s3

I'm configuring a new Drupal installation, and I installed the MediaMover module so that I could take media and put it on Amazon S3. However, when I try to enable the S3 module within Media Mover and hit Save Settings, it results in a `Server 500 Error` every time. Is there something I might be missing that would cause this? It says its only dependency is the MediaMover api, which is installed and eneabled. Or maybe some configuration that is needed that I have missed...

Comment: Could be a memory issue... how much are you giving php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of a 500 error can be found in your server's logs: it can be any number of issues, ranging from a server misconfiguration to permissions to bugs with the module itself.

Once you identify what is actually happening, and if you deterimine it's not your server's configuration, you're going to want to file an issue on [Media Mover's issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/media_mover).

Comment: The weird thing is that it doesn't seem to be producing an error in the log....The only error it generates is that its missing the favicon..

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening to me.

If try to submit the settings page on the S3 module and the php5-curl is missing in the OS, it crashes with a 500.

On ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

solved the problem. No more 500 when trying to enable and submit the configuration of Amazon S3 module.